# Dynamically Resizing Arrays

Tags: arrays, vbscript

I ran into the following issue when dealing with adding to variable array sizes. The loop runs one time more then it should essentially. But I'm curious as to what would cause this behavior? Am I not quite understanding how the loop exit functions are being called?

Here's the code:

```
Module Module1

Sub Main()
    Dim num(-1)
    Dim i = 0
    Console.WriteLine("Input numbers to be added, q to stop:")
    Dim input
    Dim total = 0
    Do
        ReDim Preserve num(UBound(num) + 1) : num(UBound(num)) = i 'resize the array each time before an element is added.
        input = Console.ReadLine
        If IsNumeric(input) Then 'attempt to break loop on non numeric input
            num(i) = CInt(input)
            i += 1
        Else
            Exit Do
        End If
    Loop
    total = 0
    For Each n In num
        total += n
    Next
    Console.WriteLine(Join(num))
    Console.WriteLine("Total: " & total)

    Console.ReadLine()
```

For input: `1 2 3 4 5 q`, the output I get is:

```
1 2 3 4 5 5
Total: 20
```

It adds the last element twice, which is interesting as it is not only running twice but somehow using the last numeric input even though the final input was not numeric. Does anyone know why that would be?

Comment: Couple of questions - 1) Your script doesn't look like proper VBScript. Are you sure you are using correct language? 2) Why are you assigning `num` when you are rediming it?

Comment: 1) Could be? I'm just running through a tutorial and I'm just trying to figure what I can and can't do.
2) I wanted to see if it was possible to redim without anything breaking.

Answer (score 3):

You both (jnb92, PankajJaju) should **not** grow the array **before** you are sure the input is numerical and has to be stored.

```
Dim input
Do
    input = Console.ReadLine()
    If IsNumeric(input) Then 'attempt to break loop on non numeric input
        ReDim Preserve num(UBound(num) + 1)
        num(UBound(num)) = CInt(input)
    Else
        Exit Do
    End If
Loop
```

**Update wrt comment:**

Your

```
ReDim Preserve num(UBound(num) + 1) : num(UBound(num)) = i
```

assigns `i` to `num` for each input; your

```
num(i) = CInt(input)
```

overwrites that with your numerical input, but not for the terminating `"q"`. So for your (one and only?) test case, the spurious last elemement is (accidentially) 5.

Comment: Ah, thanks makes sense, but why do you think it would've added the last number twice, if indeed the final element was empty?

Comment: I don't think (and never said) that the last number was added twice. I know (and said) that the last element got the then current value of i - 5 - and was not overwritten.

Answer (score 0):

I've used your script and tried to create a working solution

```
    Dim num, input,  total, i
    num = Array()

    i = 0
    Do
        input = Inputbox("Input numbers to be added, q to stop:")
        If IsNumeric(input) Then 'attempt to break loop on non numeric input
            ReDim Preserve num(UBound(num) + 1) 'resize the array each time before an element is added.
            num(i) = CInt(input)
            i = i + 1
        Else
            Exit Do
        End If
    Loop

    total = 0
    For Each n In num
        total = total + n
    Next
    msgbox Join(num)
    msgbox "Total: " & total
```

*Edit* - Updated answer based on @Ekkehard.Horner comments

Comment: This may 'work', but it adds an empty element to num.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. I was merely converting his code into working vbscript.